# php file upload without submit button

Tags: php, file, upload

Okay, I have read through tons of topics, but I seem to have missed something about this.
I followed a tutorial on how to upload a file via php, which worked without problems. Then I wanted to remove the submit button and hell broke loose.

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" onchange="form.submit()">
</form>
```

this is the form that is supposed to do the trick for me. I got the onchange listener to work, so my php file gets executed. I tested this with a simple echo.

```
echo "enter";
if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
    echo "enter2";
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    if ($fileError === 0){
        $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = "uploads/".$fileNameNew;
        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
        header("Location: sucess.html");
    }else{
        echo "there was an error";
    }
}
```

now as you can see, I am waiting for the file to be set, but this seems to not get true, as the second enter echo does not get executed. I tried it with a listener for the form to be submitted, but this did not work either.

I would really apreciate your help. I am somewhat experienced in programming in python and arduino, but webcode is quite new to me.

thank you for helpng me :)

Comment: You need `method="post"`

Comment: Forms default to `method="get"`, but you can't upload a file with `GET`.

Comment: Add an `else` to your `if (isset($_FILES['file']))` statement to indicate when the whole block was skipped.